# What causes VisualVM to report "CPU usage: unknown"?

Tags: java, visualvm

I am running a Java application on Java 17.0.0 from Azul - Zulu17.28+13-CA, with bundled JavaFX. Everything is working fine, except that the CPU usage simply says "unknown".  I've seen messages before about "unavailable with this JVM" or something similar to that, when I ran VisualVM on older JDKs, but this is different.

VisualVM itself is running on JDK 19.0.1.
About box reports: Azul 19.0.1; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (19.0.1+10, mixed mode, sharing)

The same version of VisualVM running on JDK 19.0.1 on a different system is able to get CPU usage for an application running on Oracle JDK 8u60 (ancient, I know).

Does the Azul JVM that I am trying to monitor not support something to do with CPU monitoring that Oracle Java does?

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and attach it here? VisualVM log would be also useful.

Comment: @TomasHurka edited to add screenshot.  Log file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsrn388fnxk1443/visualvm_logfile.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks. The <unknown> usage is caused by error in JMX communication. It was OK when you opened the application and failed some time after that. I was hoping to see some JMX exception in log file, but there is none. So I have more questions. Does the CPU monitoring worked when you opened the application in VisualVM? Are you able to reproduce it? If so, try to close the application tab in VisualVM and open it again. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @TomasHurka No, the CPU monitoring was never working.  Closing the tab and re-opening shows exactly the same "unknown".  I even re-launched VisualVm and it is still the same.

Comment: OK, this is interesting. Do the threads view and CPU sampling work?

Comment: Cau you try to run VisualVM with `-J-Dorg.graalvm.visualvm.jvm.level=100` and see if there are any jmx related exception in log file?

Comment: @TomasHurka The CPU Sampling works for a while (1-15 minutes, it varies) and then just stops updating.  I then need to close the tab and re-open it for CPU sampling to work again.  There are no jmx related exceptions in the log when I run with that property and connect to the application.

Comment: @TomasHurka When i activate CPU Sampling I do see a  NoSuchMethodException in the log file about getThreadCpuTime.  Caused by a signature mismatch for operation getThreadCpuTime: ([J) should be (long)

Comment: @TomasHurka Sorry, I just realized I'm mixing two different results.  The system that stops sampling after a few minutes is a different one that does report the CPU usage.  However the one with the unknown CPU is the one that gets the exception mentioned above, when starting CPU sampling (that doesn't spontaneously stop).

Comment: I guess we are off-topic here. Can you plese file an issue (github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues) for this problem and we can continue discuss the problem there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the JRE that the application was running on was an image made with `jlink` that lacked the `jdk.management` module.  When that module was added to the JRE, the CPU usage was reported properly.

More details at [GH-479](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/479).